# Power series solution of $f'' + (z^{-1})f'+f = 0$

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series

I am trying to do what the title says, and I get to the point where I have a recursive relationship to even numbered terms of the expansion, but I'm stuck on two things.

EDIT:  we are given that f(0) = 1

EDIT 2:  We just have gone over complex power series, radius of convergence.  Thus we do not yet have advanced tools to solve this problem.  My work again so far is in the attached image link.

1. How do I get the odd numbered terms?
2. And how do I turn both even and odd term series into series notation (i.e. how to get $a_k$)?

Thanks!

[my work so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bZObV.jpg)

Comment: Would you please typeset your work in your post?

Comment: You are attempting to find a series solution about $z_0=0$, yet $0$ is a singular point. You may need the Method of Frobenius.

Comment: I only see $f''$ in your hand writing not $f'''$ as shown in the title.

Comment: I have edited the question, sorry about the confusion!!

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales Im not entirely sure you can say that $z_0=0$ is singular.  Until you know what $f'$ is you really dont know what $z^{-1}f'$ looks like. Suppose $f'=gz$. Am I off base here?

Comment: Can you show the work youve done so far?  Id be curious to see how you got as far as you did and what your hangup might be.

Comment: @CogitoErgoCogitoSum OP has changed the equation since I last looked at it, but $z^{-1}$ still fails to be analytic at $0$. I actually just finished solving his original equation using Frobenius.

Comment: Perhaps I dont know where youre coming from, John, but I have no problem solving the DE as is.  The $z^{-1}$ causes no issues so far as I can see, solving it as per the requested power series expansion method. The solution for $f(z)$ ends up being one of the Bessel functions, and in fact Wolfram Alpha confirms my results.

Comment: @CogitoErgoCogitoSum That's why I said "may" instead of "will." I have not looked at it since OP changed $y^{\prime\prime\prime}$ to $y^{\prime\prime}$.

Comment: I for one am getting all $a_{\mathrm{odd}}=0$.  For evens, I am getting an alternating sequence of sub-terms.  Starting with $[1, 1/4, 1/64, 1/288, 1/18432,\ldots]$.  The recursion is $a_k = -\frac{a_{k-2}}{k^2}$ starting with $a_0=1$.

Comment: @CogitoErgoCogitoSum my work is on the attached image.  what would be the radiance of convergence for that then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the power series solution of

\begin{equation}zf^{\prime\prime}+f^\prime+zy=0\tag{1}\end{equation}

Since $z=0$ is a regular singular point of the equation, will attempt the Method of Frobenius.

Let
\begin{eqnarray}
f&=&\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nz^{n+r}\\
f^\prime&=&\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(n+r)a_nz^{n+r-1}\\
f^{\prime\prime}&=&\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(n+r)(n+r-1)a_nz^{n+r-2}\\
\end{eqnarray}

Then

\begin{eqnarray}
zf^{\prime\prime}+f^\prime+zf&=&z^r\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(n+r)(n+r-1)a_nz^{n-1}\\
&+&z^r\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(n+r)a_nz^{n-1}+z^r\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nz^{n+1}\\
&=&z^r\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(n+r)^2a_nz^{n-1}+z^r\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nz^{n+1}\\
&=&0
\end{eqnarray}
For $z\ne0$ this implies that
\begin{equation}
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(n+r)^2a_nz^{n-1}+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nz^{n+1}=0
\end{equation}
Separating out the $z$ terms with negative exponents results in the following:
\begin{equation}
r^2a_0z^{-1}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(n+r)^2a_nz^{n-1}+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nz^{n+1}=0
\end{equation}

Thus, the indicial equation is $r=0$. So, although the equation is not analytic at $z=0$, the equation could have been solved without using the Frobenius Method.

\begin{equation}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n^2a_nz^{n-1}+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nz^{n+1}=0
\end{equation}

After calibrating the sums we get

\begin{equation}
a_1+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}[(n+1)^2a_{n+1}-a_{n-1}]=0
\end{equation}
So $a_1=0$ and we get a recursive relation

\begin{equation}
a_{n+1}=\frac{a_{n-1}}{(n+1)^2}\text{ for }n\ge1
\end{equation}
Thus, all the odd power terms are $0$ and the even powered terms satisfy

$$ a_{2n}=\frac{a_0}{2^{2n}(n!)^2} $$

giving one solution

$$ f=a_0\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{2n}}{2^{2n}(n!)^2} $$

As is frequently the case when expanding about a singular point, this gives us just one of two linearly independent solutions. To find a second linearly independent solution it will be necessary to use reduction of order.

But I will give you a hint: If you multiply equation $(1)$ by $z$ you get

$$ z^2f^{\prime\prime}+zf^\prime+z^2y=0\tag{2} $$

Recall that

$$ z^2f^{\prime\prime}+zf^\prime+(z^2-\nu^2)y=0\tag{3} $$

is Bessel's equation. So what we have is Bessel's equation with $\nu=0$.